# Need help changing a Pandas datarframe column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

So im trying to create a stock game program, and i have code that says exactly what the stocks will do. For example if it will go up and down and what value it will go up and down. I have all my stocks and their values in a pandas datafram but i dont know how to change the value of the stock in my dataframe, using my code i have that says what the stock is doing

I tried doing an if statement that said if Stocks_change = stocks[x] + " " + change [y] + " " + str(money[z]):, where stocks_change is the line that says what the stock would do, I would then get the stock value in my dataframe, index it with stocks[x] and then change its corresponding value using money[z]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get help on Stack Overflow, you need to read the announcements  and think about **how to ask.**  I will give link to you about most important announcements. [minimal-reproducible-example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Read it and edit your questions so that you can have a good experience on Stack Overflow.

Comment: please, write you full dataframe and i will try help you.

Comment: post code snippet what have u tried and ur expected result with sample data

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, for example:

```py
stocks = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'AMZN']
changes = [10, -20, 30]

for stock, change in zip(stocks, changes):
    # Find the index of the stock 
    index = df_stocks.index[df_stocks['Stock'] == stock].tolist()[0]

    df_stocks.at[index, 'Value'] += change
```

Comment: Please don't answer incomplete questions. The OP only stated a requirement, provided no code, no data, no issues, and left everything up to the Community.